# angular 11: image path is given from assets after `Ng build` in s3 is listing directly under `dist` folder and `dist->assets` is wont created

Tags: angularjs, asset-pipeline, aws-codebuild, buildspec

[it is s3 location after files deployed,it shows like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9rNS.png) but[i need it like this for the path cofigured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HcezX.png)

all the assets files are out side of the assets folder and asset folder wont created.
the image path is defined by assets folder.